# How to delete status from Facebook page with using Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, koala, fb-graph

I am trying these gems: **FbGraph** and **Koala**, but with no success.

How I am trying to do it with Koala:

```
delete_it = Koala::Facebook::GraphAPI.new(data.facebook_access_token)
delete_it.delete_object(fb_post_id)
```

The result is

```
Koala::Facebook::ClientError in ...
type: GraphMethodException, code: 100, message: Unsupported delete request. [HTTP 400]
```

Thus, how to do that?

Thanks

Comment: As mentioned here (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/) you can only delete posts created by your app. Is that the case in your example? Furthermore, I read some stuff about prepending the object id with the used_id. I don't know if that still holds, can you try it?

Comment: Yes, it is. I created this post by my application and now I would like to remove this post again through my application.